# Template Template Parameters: What rule is applied in the following example

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-templates, using-declaration

Assume the following example

```
using namespace std;
template <template <typename> class>
struct X 
{
   X() 
   { 
      std::cout << "1"; 
   }
};

template <typename>
struct Y {};

template <typename T>
using Z = Y<T>;

 template <>
 struct X<Y> 
 {
   X() 
   { 
      std::cout << "2"; 
    }
 };

 int main() 
 {
   X<Y> x1;
   X<Z> x2;
 }
```

The expression  `X<Y> x1` it is clear that is use the specialization that prints "2"

The second one is strange. Doing analysis the `X<Z>` is translated to `X< Y < T > >`. I expect to print "1" . But running the code this prints "2". Which rule is applied in the second one?

Comment: If it were translated to `X< Y < T > >`, you'd get an error because `T` is undefined (and another error because `Y<T>` is not a template (as required by `X`), it's a class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The second one is strange. Doing analysis the `X<Z>` is translated to `X< Y < T > >`. I expect to print "1" . But running the code this prints "2".

No.

You have that `Z<T>` is defined as `Y<T>` so `Y` and `Z` are the same thing.

And isn't true that `X<Z>` is translated to `X<Y<T>>` (and `X<Y<T>>` can't match because `Y<T>` is a type where `X` accept only template-template arguments).